# When click a link, Need to add checked attribute in radio button

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please Some help me how to do it, I am trying by jquery but didn't work:

[image]

Comment: paste your html as well

Comment: Provide your html and js code so that some one can help.

Comment: This is a debugging question, for it to be on-topic we need clear problem and interrogatory statements, example input, expected output, actual output, and a [mcve]. Please consider taking the [tour], reading [ask], finding out what is on-topic in the [help/on-topic], then [edit]ing your question to be on-topic. Check out the [advanced editing help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting supported by Stack Overflow.

Comment: $('#amar_btn').click(function(){
    $('#check').attr( "checked" );
  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#linkID').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('.classradiobuttons').prop('checked',true);
})
```

use class="classradiobuttons"  on all your  check boxes that need to be checked for that paticular link  similarly give a new id to another link and do the same with other radiobutton with a new class name